# Is sound considered a subtopic of physics? What are the SI units of sound?

Tags: acoustics, frequency, si-units

Does physics cover sound? If so, why does sound not have units in the SI system, or how would we measure sounds and frequency? I guess it's debatable, but why isn't it standard practice in physics?

Comment: C'mon, show some research effort: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound) even has a section called "physics of sound". (Though it did not start with *"In physics[...]"* when you asked this question, granted...)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, physics covers sound.

The SI unit of frequency is [hertz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hertz) ($\mathrm{Hz}$), which is the same as $\mathrm{s^{-1}}$. The intensity of sound may be measured in [pascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(unit)) ($\mathrm{Pa}$), or in [decibels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel) ($\mathrm{dB}$) relative to a standard reference level. Pascals are the official SI unit, but decibels, which are not an SI unit, are commonly used in applications and are accepted by many standards bodies.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that, I guess I'll just keep working until they are common practice for me.

Comment: I believe the official SI unit is Pascals (pressure).  Feel free to correct me.   dB has to have a reference pressure, as it's a relative, not absolute, value.

Comment: @CarlWittgoft you're right, I should have mentioned pascals. Decibels are what you'll find used in practice. I'll edit when I'm at a computer.

Comment: Even though audio people usually just say decibels, what they typically mean is [dB SPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure).  This unit takes $20\ \mu\text{Pa}$ as the reference level, since decibels alone are actually just a way of comparing any two values logarithmically.

Comment: I'm really sorry because I'm not the brightest crayon in the box and this is probably another stupid question but with these units is it possible to find out the natural frequency of everything, is there equations   for determining the natural frequency of an object?

Comment: @user41841  That's an interesting question, but a very different one which you might post separately.  Be aware, at the very least, that some objects have a "natural," or resonant, frequency which is amplitude-dependent.  The math goes haywire fast.

Comment: Decibel is a unit used for expressing dimensionless ratios. It is annoyingly abused to refer to sound levels by taking an assumed reference level. In order to talk about sound from a physical perspective one should use pressure (SI unit is Pascal as noted by @CarlWitthoft). The standard way to use decibels with an assumed reference is to write e.g. dBW which means "decibel Watts". For example, 20dBW is 100 Watts.

Comment: @DanielSank corrected. I wouldn't necessarily say the use of decibels is an 'abuse' as such, though. As a one-time amateur sound engineer, I can attest that a logarithmic scale for sound intensity is very useful, since it corresponds pretty well to human perception.